# Sum of random number of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider independent random variables $N,X_1,...,X_k,...$, where $N$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $n$  and $X_i$ have the same distribution. $\mathbb{E} X_i = 0$, $Var (X_i) = 1$.

Then $\mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i < x) \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} dt$ as $n$ goes to infinity uniformly on $x$.

I understand how to prove it pointwise, but I am really stuck with uniformity.

Thank you.

Comment: Think you want $\mathbb P(\cdot\leq x)$ on the LHS?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: As jlammy says, you need $\leq x$ instead of $<x$ And $\sqrt n$ has to be replaced by $\sqrt N$. Do you know how to prove uniformity in the context of the usual central limit theorem?

Comment: No, this is how the problem was stated to me, I think it should be right. And I can prove central limit theorem, but only when there exists third moment.